# What optimizations should be left for compiler?

Tags: c, optimization

Assume that you have chosen the most efficient algorithm for solving a problem where performance is the first priority, and now that you're implementing it you have to decide about details like this:

`v[i*3+0]`, `v[i*3+1]` and `v[i*3+2]` contain the components of the velocity of particle `i` and we want to calculate the total kinetic energy. Given that all particles are of the same mass, one may write:

```
inline double sqr(double x)
{
    return x*x;
}

double get_kinetic_energy(double v[], int n)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
        sum += sqr(v[i*3+0]) + sqr(v[i*3+1]) + sqr(v[i*3+2]);

    return 0.5 * mass * sum;
}
```

To reduce the number of multiplications, it can be written as:

```
double get_kinetic_energy(double v[], int n)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        double *w = v + i*3;
        sum += sqr(w[0]) + sqr(w[1]) + sqr(w[2]);
    }

    return 0.5 * mass * sum;
}
```

(one may write a function with even fewer multiplications, but that's not the point of this question)

Now my question is: Since many C compilers can do this kind of optimizations automatically, where should the developer rely on the compiler and where should she/he try to do some optimization manually?

Comment: First optimization I would look for is to get rid of floating point calculations.

Comment: If optimization is the priority you *always* need to verify that the compiler output is as expected. You should never blindly assume that the compiler will do what you think it should

Comment: Note that inline is just a recommendation to the compiler.  It doesn't have to inline the code

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why? Floating point operations go 8 per cycle. I'm not sure that anything but bit operations can be faster than that.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout You are talking about some *very* specific architecture.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok, the 8 is only for the latest generations, but the basic idea holds for any Intel/Amd/Arm/Fujitsu/Power: vector instructions + pipelining has been the standard for a decade at least.

Comment: @niry That sort of index optimization is done by the compiler.

Comment: @niry `for (int i=0; i < n; i++)` is an idiomatic for loop. Your version is not. To write something like your example, you need to justify it somehow (better cache coherence or whatever).

Comment: @cup, if the compiler don't inline such a simple single-statement function, it's a very bad compiler!

Comment: If you want to use `for (int i=0; i < n; i++)` and `i * 3` I would write `for (int i=0; i < 3 * n; i += 3)` But it's unclear why you need to take them 3 at a time, when 1 at a time would be good.

Comment: Optimization should only be done, if requirements are not met. And then you need to experiment, since different architectures and compilers give you varying results. There is no silver bullet in this field. Optimization includes different algorithms and data structures, not just micro-optimization where you try to force the compiler to do something _you_ think is faster, see Chris' answer.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout @lundin First, I had an error in my previous comment - I incremented `n` instead of `i`. @Weather Vane's comment is what I meant. Second, this is totally architecture depended. Such optimization makes it worse on amd64 (multiplying every iteration is faster than incrementing by 3) and the opposite on ARMv7. I just tested it consistently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at how both **gcc** and **clang** handle your code, the micro optimisation you contemplate is vain. The compilers already apply standard common subexpression elimination techniques that remove the overhead you are trying to eliminate.

As a matter of fact, the code generated handles 2 components at a time using XMM registers.

If performance is a must, then here are steps that will save the day:

- the real judge is the wall clock. Write a benchmark with realistic data and measure performance until you get consistent results.
- if you have a profiler, use it to determine where the bottlenecks are if any.  Changing algorithms for the parts that appear to hog performance is an effective approach.
- try and get the best from the compiler: study the optimisation options and try and let the compiler use more aggressive techniques if they are appropriate for the target system. For example `-mavx512f -mavx512cd` let the **gcc** generate code that handles 8 components at a time using the 512-bit ZMM registers.

  This is a non intrusive technique as the source code does not change, so you don't risk introducing new bugs by hand optimising the code.

Optimisation is a difficult art.  In my experience, simplifying the code gets better results and far fewer bugs than adding extra subtle stuff to try and improve performance at the cost of readability and correctness.  Remember [Kernighan's Law](https://www.laws-of-software.com/laws/kernighan/): *Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.*

Looking at the code, an obvious simplification seems to generate the same results and might facilitate the optimiser's job (but again, let the wall clock be the judge):

```
double get_kinetic_energy(const double v[], int n, double mass)
{
    double sum = 0.0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 3 * n; i++)
        sum += v[i] * v[i];

    return 0.5 * mass * sum;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

> where should the developer rely on the compiler and where should she/he try to do some optimization manually?

1. Do I have fairly in-depth knowledge of the target hardware as well as how C code translates to assembler? If no, forget about manual optimizations.
2. Are there any obvious bottlenecks in this code - how do I know that it needs optimization in the first place? Obvious culprits are I/O, complex loops, busy-wait loops, naive algorithms etc.
3. When I found this bottleneck, how exactly did I benchmark it and am I certain that the problem doesn't lie in the benchmarking method itself? Experience from SO shows that some 9 out of 10 strange performance questions can be explained by incorrect benchmarking. Including: benchmarking with compiler optimizations disabled...

From there on you can start looking at system-specific things as well as the algorithms themselves - there's far too many things to look at to cover in an SO answer. It's a huge difference between optimizing code for a low-end microcontroller and a 64-bit desktop PC (and everything in between).

Answer (score 3):

One thing that looks a bit like premature optimization, but could just be ignorance of language abilities is that you have all of the information to describe particles flattened into an array of `double` values.

I would suggest instead that you break this down, making your code easier to read by creating a struct to hold the three datapoints on each particle. At that point you can create functions which take a single particle or multiple particles and do computations on them.

This will be much easier for you than having to pass three times the number of particles arguments to functions, or trying to "slice" the array. If it's easier for you to reason about, you're less likely to generate warnings/errors.

Comment: Some kinds of operations may be more convenient when dealing with xyz triples as members of a uniform array.  In the days before aggressive compiler optimization, one could safely have some code interpret data as structures while other code interpreted it as a "flattened" array, but the Standard's failure to mandate useful support for any such constructs has resulted in clang and gcc optimizers interpreting the freedom to make certain general assumptions about optimization as freedom to be willfully blind to any evidence that would prove them false in particular cases.

Answer (score 1):

Compilers like clang and gcc are simultaneously far more capable and far less capable than a lot of people give them credit for.

They have an exceptionally wide range of patterns where they can transform code into an alternative form which is likely to be more efficient and still behave as required.

Neither, however, is especially good at judging when optimizations will be useful.  Both are prone to making some "optimization" decisions that are almost comically absurd.

For example, given

```
void test(char *p)
{
    char *e = p+5;
    do
    {
        p[0] = p[1];
        p++;
    }while(p < e);
}
```

when targeting the Cortex-M0 with an optimization level below -O2, gcc 10.2.1 will generate code equivalent to calling `memmove(p, p+1, 7);`.  While it would be theoretically possible that a library implementation of memmove might optimize the n==7 case in such a way as to outperform the five-instruction byte-based loop generated at `-Og` (or even -O0), it would seem far more likely that any plausible implementations would spend some time analyzing what needs to be done, and then after doing that spend just as long executing the loop as would code generated using -O0.

What happens, in essence, is that gcc analyzes the loop, figures out what it's trying to do, and then uses its own recipe to perform that action in a manner that may or may not be any better than what the programmer was trying to do in the first place.